# Rails 3 Validations on Field from Related Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a User class that has a UserProfile class. The email is stored in the User table because they need to login with it, however, from my `user_profiles#edit` method, I'd like to be able to update this email address.

How can I place validations on the email field?

My class looks something like this (obviously not right, but you get the idea):

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :email_format => true  

  def email=(email)
    self.user.email = email
    self.user.save
  end
end
```

My form parameters will look something like:

```
{
   "user_profile" => { "first_name" => "John", "email" => "qwerty", ....
}
```

The EmailValidator is just taken from Railscasts:

```
class EmailFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator  
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)  
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i  
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly")  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your validation in the user model. When you call save on the user model, then those validations are checked.

And you need to add the following to the association:

```
belongs_to :user, :validate => true, :autosave => true
```

And remove the save call from the email= method, because now the user is saved automatically.

Comment: It will not cascade back to the UserProfile though. The form still says it successfully saved, although the email address did no actually change when calling update_attributes.